# Textarea functions don't work with contenteditable elements that are not textareas

Tags: textarea, scrollbar, scrolltop, tampermonkey

I'm trying to make a scrollbar stay down with this function (Tampermonkey, on the website: 'https://dictation.io/speech'):

```
setInterval(function() {
   document.getElementsByClassName('ql-editor').scrollTop = document.getElementsByClassName('ql-editor').scrollHeight;
     }, 500);
```

It worked before on another website.

I've fixed the height of the text box, so this scrollbar appears when there is enough of text:

```
div.notepad {
  height : 771px;
}
```

[image: the image of the website]

I've tried doing this:

```
setInterval(function() {
   document.getElementById("speech").scrollTop = document.getElementById("speech").scrollHeight;
     }, 500);
```

and this (to make it read only, but it also doesn't work):

```
document.getElementById("speech").readOnly = true;
document.getElementsByClassName("ql-editor").readOnly = true;
```

I'm simply trying to keep the scrollbar always down. And I tried all possible ids and classnames. It worked very well on another website (the textbox was such: `<textarea class="-metrika-nokeys" name="docel" id="docel" style="width: 100%;" cols="80" rows="20" spellcheck="true"></textarea>`). But nothing has any effect on the text box on this website. 
Thank you for any help in advance!

P.S. The problem is universal. This code (and when it's ".ql-editor" instead of '#speech') also doesn't work:

```
var input = document.querySelector('#speech');
var textarea = document.querySelector('#speech');

var reset = function(e) {
    var context = this;

  setTimeout(function() {
    var len = context.value.length;
    context.setSelectionRange(len, len);
  }, 100);
};

input.addEventListener('copy', reset, false);
textarea.addEventListener('copy', reset, false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it (probably not the best solution) by creating a textarea, copying text there from the div, and applying all those functions to that textarea.
Here is the code:

Creating a textarea:

```
var div = document.getElementById("speech");
var input = document.createElement("textarea");
input.setAttribute("id", "normaltext");
input.name = "post";
input.cols = "80";
input.rows = "2";
div.appendChild(input); //appendChild
```

Copying everything from the div to the textarea:

```
setInterval(function copyText() {
    $("#normaltext").val($(".ql-editor").text());
}, 100);
```

Applying functions:

```
var input1 = document.querySelector('#normaltext');
var textarea1 = document.querySelector('#normaltext');

var reset = function(e) {
    var context = this;

  setTimeout(function() {
    var len = context.value.length;
    context.setSelectionRange(len, len);
  }, 100);
};

input1.addEventListener('copy', reset, false);
textarea1.addEventListener('copy', reset, false);




setInterval(function() {
   document.getElementById("normaltext").scrollTop = document.getElementById("normaltext").scrollHeight;
     }, 500);
```

That works for me, but maybe someone will come up with a better solution.